# Linking related [identification-request] questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Shouldn't there be a way to link [identification-request](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) questions that are essentially asking for the same title even though the OP might be mistaken of the details when the question was asked?

They aren't exactly duplicates. Or are they?

How should such questions be handled? Do we have a mechanism/policy to handle the same? If not, should we define one?

Comment: Related: [What is this site's policy on closing story-identifications as duplicates when they are not accepted?](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1160/58)

Comment: Related discussion on another site - https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7065/30512 .  Their practice seems to work.

Comment: Related: https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1797/what-should-be-our-standard-for-closing-identification-request-questions-as-dupl